# Change a constant variable without rebuilding C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I've developed a c++ project with visual studio 2015. The output of my project is a single executable that must have a unique ID for every client and this ID must be accessible inside the code. A simple approach is to just define a constant variable inside the code and change its value for every client and build it many times but I have a Linux server and I'm not sure I can build it simply because I've used many Winapi libraries. I was thinking that maybe there is another way to change or add some constant value to the output like manipulating the executable.
For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


const std::string ID = "some unique ID";

int main() {
    std::cout << "Your ID: " << ID << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Put the id in a configuration file? Pass it as an argument to the program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My project output must be a single executable and should not have any files besides it. Can you explain a little more, which configuration? Thanks

Comment: prepend and append some searchable strings and use sed/python to replace the ID between those in the binary?

Comment: @aloMalbarez I think this would work but how can I implement that, should I define the constant and open the binary and search for it?

Comment: humm not much a fan of regexp, maybe some bash guru can build up a solution? but yeah the idea is to know where to find the ID and replace it  (binary file, known length, etc..)

Comment: @MasoudR. *My project output must be a single executable and should not have any files besides it.* -- So how does your client install your program?  Isn't an installation program used?  In that installation script, that is when you can alter the executable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually the executable is not directly fed to a client, it is a part of another application and If I wanted that way wouldn't ask here.

Comment: well I assumed he will provide a download link to a custom executable wich has the ID assigned to that particular downloader, so hot patching a standard executable could be an alternative to recompile the whole thing (btw the ID could be also being encrypted at patch time and decrypted at runtime)

Comment: @aloMalbarez Thanks, is there any example for this way?

Comment: @MasoudR. -- First, is this a Windows program?  If so, you can create a [string resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change it directly in the executable.  I know this violates your rule of not having another program, but [just to illustrate that it can be done](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).  You just need to figure out the mechanism to do it.

Comment: maybe this link can help http://everydaywithlinux.blogspot.com.ar/2012/11/patch-strings-in-binary-files-with-sed.html

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes it is a windows program. Thank you I will get into it.

Comment: @aloMalbarez I will try to post a sample here. Thanks.

Comment: XD just realized, once you know the offset you just write a patcher in c that opens the file lseek, write and close. if the executable is signed it will invalidate the thing, but normal executables should work.

Comment: @aloMalbarez The link you provided is too complicated for me, I think there might be a simpler way to just search in the binary file for "some unique id" and replace it with "new unique id".

Comment: yup some default ID (that won't work) but can be replaced by a valid ID

Comment: here try this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214824/258399

Comment: @aloMalbarez Thanks It worked for me. I try to create a simple bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are only two approaches. One is just building the project inside a Linux environment which is a better method but must be used some tools like `Mono XBuild` [link here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/xbuild/).
Another option which may be simpler is just open the binary file and manipulate the specific string. As @aloMalbarez comment Here is a simple script based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214820/patching-a-binary-with-dd/214824#214824).
Suppose this example: (I used 50 `m`s as a fixed length for my ID)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#define ID "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm"


using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Your ID: " << ID << "\nlen:" << strlen(ID) <<  endl;
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

After generating the executable use the following script to create output.
I'm not a Linux guy so you can help me improve this.
`./build.sh input.exe output.exe "myfixedID"`

```
#!/bin/bash
# build.sh input_file output_file <ID>


input_file=$1
output_file=$2
ID=$3


if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]; then
  echo "wrong parameters"
  echo "build.sh input_file output_file <ID>"
  exit 1
fi

# use fixed string (ID) in the source file
# this creates 50 of "m"s
search_value=$(printf 'm%.0s' {1..50})

extension=".back"
temp_file="$input_file$extension"
tmpstring_file="./tmp"
null_termin='\0'


echo "copying the original file..."
yes | cp -rf $input_file $temp_file

address=$(strings -t d $temp_file | grep $search_value | grep -o '[0-9]*')

echo "Address:"
echo $address
if ! [[ $address =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "cannot find valid ID in executable"
  echo "removing temps"
  rm $temp_file
  exit 1
fi


# make the tempstring file
printf "$ID$null_termin" > $tmpstring_file

dd if=$tmpstring_file of=$temp_file obs=1 seek=$address conv=notrunc

echo "make new file"
yes | cp -rf $temp_file $output_file

echo "removing temps"

rm $temp_file $tmpstring_file

echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

In init function of your program. Generate a unique id based of SHA-1 
 hash of current time, IP address, username (same more). you can do whatever you want to do in that program afterward (i.e save in database). Will that work ?

Comment: Thanks, but the ID is constant and must be known to the server, and It is not a good idea to build 1000 times for every possible client.

Comment: Can client and server generate ID based on same information. For example, based on username, email address, userid (using hash function like SHA-1)? so, server can know client without explicting passing information ?

Comment: @ You are right and it would possible in that way but the server has no idea what is a client and need to just make the executable with a unique id and that is it.

Answer (score -4):

A Constant is not a Variable, they are opposite types.  A Constant is an element that is assigned a particular value that does not change, thus the word constant, unchanging.
A Variable on the other hand is an element that is stored in memory as a changeable value, as your program runs, the VARIABLE can change it's current value.

In Visual Studio, you can create a configuration file that passes set values to your program, these values are variable, and can be changed programmatically and manually.  But, as you stated you do not want a separate file to look up information from.

If you want to track users by their Unique ID, then you must have a database somewhere that can record new users and issue a unique ID, or, you can create a unique ID based on the date and time that the account is created, if you are creating a unique executable for each one, the date/time information is included in the file creation information, so you would simply use that, since every file is created at a unique date/time, that would always indicate the ID.  You could keep the same name for each file, or incorporate the date/time into the filename, like myPro20180522183231.exe which would be year 2018 month 05 day 22 hour 18 minutes 32 seconds 31 and this could be confirmed through the date/time information of the file creation data.